# shell command for ps

Tags: shell

What's the difference between the following two commands. I know the output is different but what is that = sign before rss?

```
$ ps -orss -p 62277
   RSS
111636

$ ps -o rss= -p 62277
111636
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-o` specifies that you will be listing the columns that you want displayed.
Adding an `=` after the column name (rss in this case), gives you the opportunity to override the default value for the column header, you could put `-o rss=ResidentSet` for example, but with an empty `=`, you are saying 'no column header'.